# File Path button missing in source step after upgrading Power Query

Tags: power-query

After upgrading MS Power Query to the Dec 6 version I noticed that in my existing query for cleaning up a CSV file that the "file path" button is missing in the source step.

Prior to the upgrade I would open the excel file with the query, edit the query, double click on source step, then click the browse button to choose a new file.

Now I have to open Windows explorer to copy the file path to the clipboard and paste it into the source step.

System Specs:

Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2013 32bit

Microsoft Power Query 2.39.4526.123 32bit

What I tried:

-- In place upgrade (still same issue)

-- Uninstalled, reboot, and installed version above

Any ideas on how to fix?

If this is a bug, how can I report it to Microsoft?

Comment: Just now I tried creating a new query that opens a CSV file and cleans it up.  Once the query is saved and data is displayed in a table I still run into the same issue when editing the source step in the query.

Comment: Can you download the latest version and see if it's still an issue? You can report issues by using the Send a Frown feature, which can be access through the Power Query ribbon.